# Calculate the third and fourth nearest neighbours in bcc

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, crystallography

My textbook has given data for third and fourth nearest neighbours to be 12 and 8 with distances $\sqrt{2}a$ and $\frac{\sqrt{11}a}{2}$.

I have been able to calculate for  the first and second nearest neighbour but it has become difficult to visualise for the other two to calculate. Can you help me with hints on how to proceed preferably with a diagram.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With $\sqrt3\over2$ being that close to $1$, BCC packing is better *not* looked at in terms of coordination spheres. But if you insist...

Say you are sitting in the center of a cell. Then:

- Your first neighbours are at the corners of the same cell.
- Second neighbours are at the centers of the nearest adjacent cells.
- Third neighbours: centers of the *next adjacent cells* (those which share **two** corners with your cell).
- Fourth neighbours: far corners of the nearest adjacent cells.

On a side note, there are more than just 8 of the latter.

Comment: "BCC packing is better not looked at in terms of coordination spheres" then in what terms should we look at it instead?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Two interpenetrating cubic lattices would do.

Comment: ...as the one mentioned in Oscar's answer? ("two simple cubic lattice, one with points at coordinates $(ma,na,pa)$ where $m,n,p$ are integers, the other with points at $((m+(1/2))a,(n+(1/2))a,(p+(1/2))a)$")

Comment: Yeah, that one.

Comment: Although it is quite common to look at the radial distribution function from x-ray diffraction and find the peaks corresponding to the nth nearest neighbors. From that perspective, 'coordination spheres' make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Jon You know full well that the peaks have _widths_. How far shall we go before we stop being able to tell one peak from the next?

Comment: Getting out to 3rd and 4th nearest neighbors is not a problem, particularly in something like bcc (triclinic, now that is a different story). I don't think anyone is going to ask you about 20th nearest neighbors, since they aren't exactly near!

Comment: @Jon Not a problem? In a nice crystalline bcc, sure; but then you'd probably do a single crystal job (or Rietveld, for that matter, since there aren't awfully many parameters to refine) and never bother about RDFs in the first place. In a distorted nanoparticle stuff... not so sure anymore.

Comment: Sure, but in polycrystalline material that isn't distorted nano you can get out pretty far. Fine grained iron alloys for example...

Comment: Yeah, in that case I guess you can. I just wanted to point out that there are cases when you can't.

Comment: What does your first line mean by the way?

Comment: Just what it says. You can easily tell 1.5 from 1 and build a theory on that, but with 1.15 against 1, you won't be so sure.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me how to spot the 4th nearest neighbour using the atom on the corner (instead of the centre one)?

Comment: @Abcd Use my construction, write down the vectors from the centre to the 4th neighbours, then apply the same vectors to the corner atom.

Answer (score 10):

You can think of the body centered cubic lattice as two simple cubic lattice, one with points at coordinates $(ma,na,pa)$ where $m,n,p$ are integers, the other with points at $((m+(1/2))a,(n+(1/2))a,(p+(1/2))a)$.  If you work out increasing distances for both omponent cubic lattices you get, in units of $a$:

$\sqrt{0^2+0^2+1^2}=1$

$\sqrt{0^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$

$\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{0^2+0^2+2^2}=2$ -- generally square roots of whole numbers

and also

$\sqrt{(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2}=\sqrt{3}/2$

$\sqrt{(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2+(3/2)^2}=\sqrt{11}/2$

$\sqrt{(1/2)^2+(3/2)^2+(3/2)^2}=\sqrt{19}/2$

$\sqrt{(3/2)^2+(3/2)^2+(3/2)^2}=3\sqrt{3}/2$ -- generally half the square roots of numbers that are 3 more than multiples of 8.  Each component square under the radical is one fourth of an odd square, and each odd square is one more than a multiple of 8.

Incidentally, there are not eight fourth-nearest neighbors.  There are 24.  The $3/2$ coordinate may occur along any one of three axes and each nonzero coordinate can independently have a negative sign.